# ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: 'certificateTextPlacements'. FormArray inside FormArray

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

https://angular-ivy-hmuyfw.stackblitz.io

I am having trouble with Angular errors since trying to embed a FormArray inside a FormArray.

These are my methods for dealing with the form:

```
// Return index 0 because the array only ever had 1 entry
certificateTextPlacements(): FormArray {
  const certificateVersions = this.certificateForm.controls.certificateVersions as FormArray;
  return certificateVersions.at(0).get('certificateTextPlacements') as FormArray;
}

newCertificateTextPlacement(name, xPos, yPos): FormGroup {
  return this.fb.group({
    name,
    xPos,
    yPos,
    highlightedColour: 'transparent'
  });
}

addCertificateTextPlacement(name, xPos, yPos) {
  this.certificateTextPlacements().push(this.newCertificateTextPlacement(name, xPos, yPos));
}

removeCertificateTextPlacement(i: number) {
  this.certificateTextPlacements().removeAt(i);
}

private _createForm() {
  this.certificateForm = this.fb.group({
    name: '',
    code: '',
    nextIssueNumber: '',
    certificateVersions: this.fb.array([])
  });

  this.certificateForm.addControl('certificateVersions', this.fb.group({
    pdfData: '',
    version: '',
    certificateTextPlacements: this.fb.array([])
  }));

  const control = this.certificateForm.controls.certificateVersions as FormArray;
  control.push(
    this.fb.group({
      pdfData: '',
      version: '',
      certificateTextPlacements: this.fb.array([])
    })
  );

  this.newCertificateTextPlacement('test', 1, 1);
}
```

I am trying to loop over the form and access the certificateTextPlacements using the following HTML:

```
<div [formGroup]="certificateForm">
  <div formArrayName="certificateTextPlacements">
    <div *ngFor="let certificateTextPlacement of certificateTextPlacements().controls; let i = index;">
      <div class="example-container">
          <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
            <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
            <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Name" formControlName="name" (focus)="highlightEditingTextPlacement(i);" required>
          </mat-form-field>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is the error `Cannot find control with name: 'certificateTextPlacements'`

If I console.log(this.certificateForm.value) then I see the exact structure I designed, which is good. The problem is accessing that structure, looping over the array returned from `certificateTextPlacements()` and creating frontend results

Comment: Can you pls implement it in stackblitz. so, that  we can find easily the solution.Your certificate form doesn't have the certificateTextPlacements control. it have certificateVersions only

Comment: https://angular-ivy-hmuyfw.stackblitz.io

Comment: @MskSatheesh - I'm sorry to ask this, but where would I add that control? My brain has been editing/changing this code for 24 hours and i've become "tunnel visioned" :)

Comment: Pls share the editor url

Comment: @MskSatheesh - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hmuyfw?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: In createForm function you already created the control certificateVersions but u adding the control again to the formGroup.

Comment: If u need to add a formGroup to the formArray, first u need to get the formArray as follows   let formArr = this.certificateForm.get('certificateVersions') as FormArray; and then u need to push the formGroup to that formArr

Comment: @MskSatheesh - That helps a lot! Thank you for the description and i'm sure I will solve the problem with your comments

Comment: @MskSatheesh - I have tried your suggestion but the same problem still exists - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hmuyfw?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: formArr.push is not a function:

const formArr = this.certificateForm.get('certificateTextPlacements') as FormArray;
    formArr.push(this.fb.group({
      name: new FormControl(''),
      xPos: new FormControl(''),
      yPos: new FormControl(''),
      highlightedColour: new FormControl('')
    }));

Comment: I need only one array of fields or with in the array u need another array of fields

Comment: @MskSatheesh - This is the structure I need - https://pastebin.com/sKkZ35TK

certificateVersions - array but only ever 1 item. It needs to be an array because the REST endpoint needs it as an array